# Multiple Rhino (java) threads manipulate the same file

Tags: javascript, java, multithreading, synchronization, rhino

I am writing a piece of javascript (ecmascript) within a 3rd-party application which uses embedded Rhino. The application may start multiple Java threads to handle data concurrently. It seems that every Java thread starts its own embedded Rhino context which in turn runs my script.

The purpose of my script is, to receive data from the application and use it to maintain the contents of a particular file. I need a fail-safe solution to handle the concurrency from my script.

So far, what I have come up with is to call out to java and use `java.nio.channels.FileLock`. However, the documentation [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/channels/FileLock.html) states:

> File locks are held on behalf of the entire Java virtual machine. They are not suitable for controlling access to a file by multiple threads within the same virtual machine.

Sure enough, the blocking call `FileChannel.lock()` does not block but throws an exception, leading to the following ugly code:

```
var count = 0;
while ( count < 100 )
{
    try 
    {
        var rFile = new java.io.RandomAccessFile(this.mapFile, "rw");
        var lock = rFile.getChannel().lock();
        try
        {
            // Here I do whatever the script needs to do with the file
        }
        finally
        {
            lock.release();
        }
        rFile.close();
        break;
    } catch (ex) {
        // This is reached whenever another instance has a lock
        count++;
        java.lang.Thread.sleep( 10 );
    }       
}
```

**Q: How can I solve this in a safe and reliable manner?**

I have seen posts regarding Rhino `sync()` being similar to Java `synchronized` but that does not seem to work between multiple instances of Rhino.

**UPDATE**

I have tried the suggestion of using `Synchronizer` with `org.mozilla.javascript.tools.shell.Global` as a template:

```
function synchronize( fn, obj )
{
    return new Packages.org.mozilla.javascript.Synchronizer(fn).call(obj);
}
```

Next, I use this function as follows:

```
    var mapFile = new java.io.File(mapFilePath);
    // MapWriter is a js object
    var writer = new MapWriter( mapFile, tempMap );
    var on = Packages.java.lang.Class.forName("java.lang.Object");
    // Call the writer's update function synchronized
    synchronize( function() { writer.update() } , on );
```

However I see that two threads enter the `update()` function simultaneously. What is wrong with my code?

Comment: sync() does work between all contexts in a single Rhino instance, and across all instances of Rhino running in a single VM, which I assume is what we're talking about (it uses Java synchronization, so could also coordinate with native Java concurrency tools).

Comment: My guess, without being able to test your setup (and without testing my theory myself), is that a function can't be called with `Class java.lang.Object` as `this`.

Try `return new Packages.org.mozilla.javascript.Synchronizer(fn,obj)` and then invoke the returned function:

`synchronize(function() { writer.update() }, on)();`

and see if that is better.

Comment: I get an error `org.mozilla.javascript.EvaluatorException: Java constructor for "org.mozilla.javascript.Synchronizer" with arguments "function,java.lang.Class" not found.` Looking at the source, there is indeed no constructor for that, I have to pass in ( Scriptable, Object ).

Comment: Yeah, but everything is an object. There must be some issue with how Rhino is translating the argument. Or you're on an earlier version of Rhino, perhaps? What does `Packages.org.mozilla.javascript.Context.getCurrentContext().getImplementationVersion()` give you?

Comment: Perhaps you are right: `Rhino Version: Rhino 1.6 release 7 2007 08 19` that seems a bit old. Unfortunately I have no control over (this release of) the application. I will tell the development team to start using a [rd]ecent version in the next release though.

Comment: What's weird: in the server.log, it states: `Rhino Initialized, implementation version: Rhino 1.7 release 3 2011 05 09`. As if there are two different versions in use.

Comment: Using a newer version would help because it gives you the two-argument version of Synchronizer. You can probably coax the one-argument version to do what you want but you're probably going to need to somehow hack something together that tucks a shared target (JavaScript object!) somewhere where everyone can see it and then uses that target as `this` for the function.

Comment: OK, thanks a lot for all your thorough explanations. Marking your answer as correct because it would work were it not for the archaic version of Rhino I encountered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depending how Rhino is embedded, there are two possibilities:

1. If the code is executed in the Rhino shell, use the `sync(f,lock)` function to turn a function into a function that synchronizes on the second argument, or on the `this` object of its invocation if the second argument is absent. (Earlier versions only had the one-argument method, so unless your third-party application uses a recent version, you may need to use that or roll your own; see below.)
2. If the application is not using the Rhino shell, but using a custom embedding that does not include concurrency tools, you'll need to roll your own version. The source code for `sync` is a good starting point (see the source code for [Global](https://github.com/mozilla/rhino/blob/master/toolsrc/org/mozilla/javascript/tools/shell/Global.java) and [Synchronizer](https://github.com/mozilla/rhino/blob/master/src/org/mozilla/javascript/Synchronizer.java); you should be able to use Synchronizer pretty much out-of-the-box the same way Global uses it).

It is possible that the problem is that the object on which you are trying to synchronize is not shared across contexts, but is created multiple times by the embedding or something. If so, you may need to use some sort of hack, especially if you have no control over the embedding. If you have no control over the embedding, you could use some kind of VM-global object on which to synchronize, like `Runtime.getRuntime()` or something (I can't think of any that I immediately know are single objects, but I suspect several of those with singleton APIs like `Runtime` are.)

Another candidate for something on which to synchronize would be something like `Packages.java.lang.Class.forName("java.lang.Object")`, which should refer to the same object (the `Object` class) in all contexts unless the embedding's class loader setup is extremely unusual.

Comment: I know for sure that `sync()` is not available (ergo custom embedding). My first try with `Synchronizer` did not work, that's why I assumed it was only for a single Rhino instance. I will look at the `Global` source code and give it another try.

Comment: Would you check out my updated post? I am clearly making a mistake somewhere.